# Set value for cell in excel file get error when open multi excel files

Tags: vba, excel, outlook-2010

I would like to write a macro in outlook to check whether is excel file opening, if this file is not opened, open it and set value for cell(1,1). Else if it is opening, just set value for cell(1,1) no need to open it again. I did it like that and it run okay.

Here is my source code to do like that

```
Sub test_3()
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim WB As Object
    Dim WS As Object
    If (IsWorkBookOpen("C:\Users\sang\Desktop\Book2.xlsm") = True) Then 'check whether is file opening? if yes
        Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        objExcel.Visible = True
        Set WB = objExcel.Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")
        WB.Activate
    Else 'file is not opening
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objExcel.Visible = True
        Set WB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\sang\Desktop\Book2.xlsm") 'open file
        WB.Activate
    End If
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    WS.Range("A1").Value = "haha" 'set value for cell
End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

But my problem is when this file is opening and a few other files are opening,too. It cannot set value for cell and get error "Subscript out of range". When I debug, error locate at "Set WB = objExcel.Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")". Could you please tell me what problem with it, and how can I solve it. Everything just run fine when just have my single excel file, and get problem when have few files are opening with it
[image]

Comment: I did like you said But when I run, I get an error "File name of class name not found during Automation operation" and when I debug it, It highlight this line "Set objExcel = GetObject("C:\Users\sang\Desktop\Book2.xlsm", "Excel.Application")" which I add more path like you said. Please help me to find out what problem with it

Comment: even though your post was answered, check my (long) code in my answer below, it will work also in cases you have multiple Excel instances open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll run into problems if there are multiple instances of `Excel.Application` running but this will work otherwise.

```
Sub TestWrite()
    Const FULLNAME As String = "C:\Users\sang\Desktop\Book2.xlsm"

    Dim objExcel As Object, WB As Object, WS As Object
    Set objExcel = getExcelAppication
    objExcel.Visible = True
    Set WB = getWorkbook(objExcel, FULLNAME)

    If WB Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "File not found: " & FULLNAME, vbInformation, ":("
    Else
        Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        WS.Range("A1").Value = "haha"
    End If

End Sub

Function getExcelAppication() As Object
    Dim objExcel As Object
    If GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='Excel.exe'").Count > 0 Then
        Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Else
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Set getExcelAppication = objExcel
End Function

Function getWorkbook(objExcel As Object, FULLNAME As String) As Object
    Dim ShortName As String
    Dim WB As Object, WS As Object
    ShortName = Right(FULLNAME, Len(FULLNAME) - InStrRev(FULLNAME, "\"))

    For Each WB In objExcel.Workbooks
        If WB.Name = ShortName Then
            Set getWorkbook = WB
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    Set getWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FULLNAME)

End Function
```

Comment: When I run macro it get error, I guess Workbooks.Open(ShortName) should be a full path instead of just file name, So, I change it to Set getWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FULLNAME). It run good, but It seem to be you reopen this file, because when this file is opening with a few other excel files, when I run macro it reopen this file and say that "Book2.xlsm is already open, Reopening will cause any changes you made to be discarded. Do you want to  reopen Book2.slsm". I don't want to reopen and get this message. How can I run macro without this message

Comment: Hello Thomas Inzina, sorry, I did it. Just change ShortName to FULLNAME in line "Set getWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ShortName)" and it run very good. Thank you so much for attemp to help

Comment: @Bruce Don't be sorry! I thought for a second that I was going crazy.  I have almost workbook with the same name.  While I was testing I could have swore there was a list on numbers and then they disappeared.  Turns Out using `ShortName` cause the workbook in my documents to open...lol.

Comment: Yes, use shortname lead to open it and it should be changed to "FULLNAME", I see you edited your question and it look great, once again, Thank you so much for your help :D

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  It was a fun question :)

Comment: @ThomasInzina , can you test the code in my answer below, I want to see if it's working also for you (I want to adapt is for future cases)

Answer (score 2):

If there's more than one instance of Excel open, then there's no guarantee that

```
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

will get the instance which has your file open in it.

Try instead

```
Set objExcel = GetObject("C:\Users\sang\Desktop\Book2.xlsm", "Excel.Application")
```

or just

```
Set objExcel = GetObject("C:\Users\sang\Desktop\Book2.xlsm")
```

Comment: I did like you said But when I run, I get an error "File name of class name not found during Automation operation" and when I debug it, It highlight this line "Set objExcel = GetObject("C:\Users\sang\Desktop\Book2.xlsm", "Excel.Application")" which I add more path like you said. Please help me to find out what problem with it

Comment: That should work - is the file definitely open in Excel?

Comment: Yes, I certainly my excel file is opening. Moreover, if just one this excel is opening (no more other excel files), it still get error like that

Comment: hello Tim Williams, It still get Error But I did it with source of Thomas Inzina, Whatever, thank you so much for attemp to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The code below will work also on multiple open Excel instances.

Part of the code that was modifed to fit this post, was taken from [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=182853)

The code below is a little long, but other than that it works very nice (tested)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
(ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long

Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Const RETURN_OK As Long = &H0
Private Const IID_IDispatch As String = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
Private Const OBJID_NATIVEOM As Long = &HFFFFFFF0

Sub ComplexTest()

    Dim hWndXL As Long
    Dim oXLApp As Object
    Dim oWB As Object         
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim WB As Object
    Dim WS As Object
    Dim FullFileName    As String
    Dim CleanFileName   As String

    FullFileName = "C:\Users\sang\Desktop\Book2.xlsm"
    CleanFileName = Right(FullFileName, Len(FullFileName) - InStrRev(FullFileName, "\"))

    ' check if the Excel's file name is already open
    If IsWorkBookOpen(FullFileName) Then                                        
         ' first Excel Window
        hWndXL = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)             
         ' got one Excel instance open ?
        Do While hWndXL > 0

             ' Get a reference to current excel instance
            If GetReferenceToXLApp(hWndXL, oXLApp) Then                     
                 ' loop through workbooks
                For Each oWB In oXLApp.Workbooks
                    If oWB.Name = CleanFileName Then
                        Set WB = oWB
                    End If
                Next
            End If

             ' Find the next Excel Window
            hWndXL = FindWindowEx(0, hWndXL, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
        Loop
    Else
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objExcel.Visible = True
        Set WB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FullFileName) 'open file
    End If

    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    WS.Range("A1").Value = "haha" 'set value for cell

End Sub

 ' This section of code was taken from Ozgrid
 ' link: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=182853
 '
 ' The Function Returns a reference to a specific instance of Excel.
 ' The Instance is defined by the Handle (hWndXL) passed by the calling procedure

Function GetReferenceToXLApp(hWndXL As Long, oXLApp As Object) As Boolean

    Dim hWinDesk As Long
    Dim hWin7 As Long
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim iID As GUID

     ' Rather than explaining, go read
     ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687262(v=vs.85).aspx
    Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_IDispatch), iID)

     ' We have the XL App (Class name XLMAIN)
     ' This window has a child called 'XLDESK' (which I presume to mean 'XL desktop')
     ' XLDesk is the container for all XL child windows....
    hWinDesk = FindWindowEx(hWndXL, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)

     ' EXCEL7 is the class name for a Workbook window (and probably others, as well)
     ' This is used to check there is actually a workbook open in this instance.
    hWin7 = FindWindowEx(hWinDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)

     ' Deep API... read up on it if interested.
     ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978(v=vs.85).aspx
    If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWin7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iID, obj) = RETURN_OK Then
        Set oXLApp = obj.Application
        GetReferenceToXLApp = True
    End If

End Function

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)

    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
        Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
        Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
        Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: @ThomasInzina did you get to test it a bit ?

Comment: Yes, I did.  For some reason `On Error Resume Next` will not escape the `Error 9 ActiveX component can't create object` thrown by a bad `getObject` call.   I am sure that it is a bad configuration on my computer. Besides that, little glitch, your code works wonderfully!!  Kudos.

Comment: @ThomasInzina thanks for testing, let me know if you get to fix it (I want to be careful before fully adapting it to other projects)

Comment: Your code works beautifully.  It's my machine.  The workaround was actually because I can't escape the error thrown by `IsWorkBookOpen`.    After I rewrote it, everything worked like a dream.  You might  consider swapping out your `IsWorkBookOpen` with mine:  [IsWorkBookOpen](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GblzBX_WvZtb8NZqYyGhyH3Z2g5e0nfEqg7S17wsWHc/edit?usp=sharing).  By testing to see if the temporary file that Excel uses for the workbook exists, I was able to cut `IsWorkBookOpen` down to 4 lines of code and not throw any errors.

Comment: I created an class to wrap your code: [ExcelLocator](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17KNAFsYBkvtoYkBNMafd0VHOl0zQaLFWqUSsd9Hxfqo/edit?usp=sharing).  I also added some functionality by extracting some of the code into separate methods.  `getOpenApplications` returns  a collection of all open Excel Applications and `getShortName` that extracts a filename from a filepath.

Comment: I will test it later tonite at home